# "Writing configuration file failed" in MySQL Server 8.0.15

Tags: mysql

While set up the configuration in MySQL Server 8.0.15

Got an error

"Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

Invalid server template

Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file"

Comment: Issue has been fixed 

This error may happen as you have an updated server but old server details in Registry Editor 

What I done is as follows, 

1. Press the Windows+R keys to open the Run dialog. 
2. Type "regedit.exe" press Enter. 
3. From within "Registry Editor" navigate to the path as given below 
"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\". 
4. Right click on [MYSQL]and choose "Delete". 
5. Close the "Registry Editor" window. 
6. Try to configure your MySql 8.0.15 Server now. 

Good Luck

Comment: doesn't help your solution with registry, I have clear windows installation

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as Sabi.  I'm on a new server that has never had MySQL installed.  The key you mentions is not present in the registry.

Answer (score 8):

Not trying to bring up anything old. How I fixed the problem was to uninstall the installer completely. You can do this by removing everything(in the list of installed items), and it'll prompt you to remove the installer. Then you can reinstall; when you reinstall it'll first ask to "update" the installer or something similar. Click Yes. Afterward, you can install it like normal.

1. Uninstall all MySQL items, including the installer
2. Reinstall the launcher, but click yes on updates
3. Should work

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem today after re-installing windows 10 and then trying to install everything I needed for work.

What helped for me was accepting the (weirdly formulated) 'update installer' prompt with 'yes'. This prompt appeared right after opening/running the installer. The first time I ignored it with 'no' because I was under the impression that downloading an installer would get me the newest version. Then I got this error. Even after retrying three times (also after uninstalling). When I tried installing again and accepted the 'update installer' prompt the problem was gone.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Accepting to update installer in the beginning worked for me when installing mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.15.0.msi

Comment: For me I had to uninstall all the installed packages since I got this error. Re-running the installed and selecting this option in the beginning of the setup fixed it for me. I used the `mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.15.0.msi` installer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled all and i have rerun the installer. I've accepted the upgraded version when on the start it prompted. The installation was completed perfectly.

Comment: Weird, But this is the solution which works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue.. For me I went for, the less the better. I only chose to download Shell and MySQL server. It did work. So I think instead of choosing All the downloads, go for the ones you require. Workbench does seem to like being solo.

Answer (score 0):

It's python version miss matched. For me I have python version 3.9 but MySQL server need python version 3.8 or less. I downloaded the old python version and problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

If you are getting this error "The configuration for MySQL Server 8.0.15 has failed" in Windows 10 While installing MySQL

`Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Invalid server template
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file`

If you have Microsoft account in Windows 10 instead to local account, Then you will need to convert your Microsoft account to local account. In order to do that follow below simple steps:

1. Open Settings > Accounts and click Your info.
2. After confirming that the account is set up to use a Microsoft
   account, click Sign in with a local account instead and follow on-screen instructions.
3. Uninstall MySQL Installer and restart the system.
4. Install [MySQL for Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html) and follow the steps.
5. Let me know if this resolves you issue :)